# How to display and store button values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

very new to coding here, apologies for the basic question. trying to complete the odin project's build-a-calculator challenge (http://www.theodinproject.com/javascript-and-jquery/on-screen-calculator)

and struggling to make numbers appear after they are clicked. Also, how would I store the value in a variable or array to then be used in a calculation later?

Here's the excerpt of my JS:

```
$(".numbers").on("click", function() {

$+(this).text()

    ;});
```

And my HTML (note I'm using jsfiddle, hence the lack of html opening and closing tags etc:

```
 <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

 <div class="numbers">
 <button type="button">0</button>

<button type="button">1</button>

<button type="button">2</button>

<button type="button">3</button>

<button type="button">4</button>

<button type="button">5</button>

<button type="button">6</button>

<button type="button">7</button>

<button type="button">8</button>

<button type="button">9</button>

 </div>

 <div class = "operators">
 <button type="button">+</button>
 <button type="button">-</button>
 <button type="button">*</button>
 <button type="button">/</button>
 <button type="button">=</button>
 <button type="button">clear</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: if you're using jsfiddle and you've set up a demo there that isolates the problem, then it would be very good to link to the jsfiddle itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the value of the buttons in a variable you could do this.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var i = $(this).text();
    console.log(i); // print the value of i in the console
});
```

Once you have the value you'll need to be able to put the value of each button clicked in order on the "display" of the calculator like so.

HTML

```
<div class="display"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var i = $(this).text();
    var display = $('.display');

    display.text( display.text() + i );
});
```

Hopefully that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Craig (and everyone else that answered)! Super helpful and especially grateful for the quick response. One last question, since my # buttons (0-9) need to do different things than my operator buttons (+, -, etc) I was hoping to reference the on.click() function's to an overarching wrapped div such as my div class = numbers. But when I use your method with $(".numbers") instead of button it doesn't work?

Comment: No problem! To answer your question, use `$('.numbers').find('button').on('click')` to attach a click handler to all `buttons` inside of your `div.numbers`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want to display your numbers. Are you using a TextArea?

For storing values, inside your function do something like

var num=$+(this).text()

Other than that, you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fruLq7wv/5/) demonstrated how to do what you want.

```
// array is defined outside the click handler
var clickedArray = [];

$('button').on('click',function() {
    // get the button that was clicked
    var buttonClicked = $(this).html();
    console.log(buttonClicked);

    // store it as the last element in the array
    clickedArray.push(buttonClicked);
    console.log(clickedArray);

    // and output it to the screen
    $('.js-calc-out').append(buttonClicked);
});
```

**Points to note:**

1. The array is defined outside the click event handler so it can be used without being reset each time a click event is fired. This array will exist until the page is refreshed or it is purposely unset and you can access it as you need it.
2. The `html()` function retrieves the contents of any given HTML element, in this case it's the clicked button, which is retrieved using `$(this)` (any element an event is fired on is retrieved using `this` which is then converted to a jquery object using the `$()` function).
3. The `push()` function is used to append the latest clicked element to the end of the array mentioned in point 1.
4. `.js-calc-out` is an HTML element to which we `append()` the latest click to, meaning the sequence of clicks are output.
5. The `console.log` declarations output some stuff into the inspector which should help you see the process develop.

PS. this is a simplified solution that takes into account your current position on the learning curve; ideally you'd want to use objects to encapsulate data and functionality in javascript and keep out of the global namespace.